Drop schemas and tables automatically
I have a SQL Server database with more than 50000 schemas.
I need to keep 500 of them.
I try to drop all unnecessary schema but it's very long.
I have to delete all tables of one schema and then the schema itself.
Is there a possibility to do this automatically?
For the moment I use something like this to drop all tables
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '';
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'DROP TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';'
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE t.type = 'U' AND t.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo');
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;


How is PLSQL relevant to a SQL Server question?

This really smells like an XY Problem, if I am honest. I'm wondering why you needed 50,000 different schemas to start with. How many objects are each of these schemas? Might it be easier to migrate what you do need to retain to a new database? If your database version controlled? (If not, why not? Seems like it really should be with this massive design.) Could you remove all the unneeded schemas, and objects, from the project and then deploy the change that way?

This is an old database with many unused schemas. The main objective is to cleanup this database. I can't migrate it baucuse it's used by a software

Anyway it should be pretty simple to write code to do this in a loop for a one off clean up. What problem are you having with that?

The main problem is my plsql level.

Plsql is oracle not SQL server

The main problem is my plsql level - ?? do you mean your knowledge/experience of plsql? or the plsql version?

You need TSQL not PLSQL. But anyway at the moment this just looks like a request for someone else to write the code for you without you making any attempt yourself.

Not sure what the problem with your code, except you shouldn't use string concat like this? Except you probably don't wanna drop dbo tables but the actual schemas you wanna drop. Just remember that backups are your friends so take them before going on a schema drop rampage

'Is there a possibility to do this automatically?' - I take this to mean can I add an expiry date (for example) to a schema and have the rdbms delete it as part of the rdbms housekeeping..then NO no such facility exists in any RDBMS that I am aware of.

if you haven't then also just check the SQL management studio, right click server then tasks > generate scripts. That dialog supports schemas and can do a lot for you.

you can use this method to expedite what you want to do, whether you should be doing it is up to you to manage the risk. Depending on factors like table sizes, logging level, disk space, etc you could fill up the database transaction log quickly by dropping a lot of objects.

Test on a replica database first
Database backup!
Verify database backup can be restored!
Create a working table with the schema names that you want to delete. You can select them from sys.schemas if you have a naming standard to follow that allows you to identify the schemas to delete. This is dangerous work if you accidentally include schemas that shouldn't be deleted. You might want to do it in smaller batches rather than kick off a drop of 50,000 schemas.

CREATE TABLE [DropSchemaList](
    [SchemaName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO DropSchemaList
SELECT s.name
FROM sys.schemas s
WHERE s.name like '%somepattern%';


Create a cursor and iterate through the schema names that you inserted into the working table, dropping the tables and then finally dropping the schema. If there are objects other than tables you will need to drop those as well.

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Cursor definition to loop through schemas to drop
DECLARE SchemaCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT SchemaName
FROM DropSchemaList;

DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(128);

OPEN SchemaCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM SchemaCursor INTO @SchemaName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'';
    
    --Create drop statements
    SELECT @sql += 'DROP TABLE [' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + ']; '
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE s.name = @SchemaName;

    --Run drop statements
    IF (@sql <> '')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'executing table drop for schema: ' + @SchemaName;
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END

    -- Drop the schema
    SET @sql = N'DROP SCHEMA [' + @SchemaName + '];';
    PRINT 'executing schema drop for schema: ' + @SchemaName;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM SchemaCursor INTO @SchemaName;
END

CLOSE SchemaCursor;
DEALLOCATE SchemaCursor;

